# Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So i get this above mentioned error when i click my hamburger. And after clicking the hamburger my whole page turns white and when i right click nothing appears at all. Where is the issue here?I searched a lot of similar problems on the internet. Theres only talks about putting the script tag at the bottom and writing the window.onload function. I have put the script tag at the bottom of the body still this is happening.
ERROR MESSAGE:
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
at Jr (chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:103527)
at Xr.updateState (chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:105004)
at chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:105819
at chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:73161
at chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:110691
at Array.forEach ()
at wi.fire (chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:110679)
at _onBgPortMessage (chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/Grammarly-check.js:2:115134)

HTML

```html
<header>
    <nav class="wrapper2">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>LO</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="form2.html">ARTICLES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#newsletter">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hamburger" onclick="open()">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="hero">
        <h1>LOMBOK</h1>
        <h2>HOLISTIC HEALTH & MORE</h2>
        <div class="bigbar"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

SASS

```
header{
    background-image: url(../images/heroimg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 65%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 10px;
    nav{
        display: none;
        justify-content:space-between;
        .logo{
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            position: relative;
            top: -10px;
        }
        .navbar ul{
            display: flex;
            width: 480px;
            justify-content: space-between;
            li{
                list-style: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
                a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: black;
                }
            }
            li:last-child{
                border: 2px solid black;
                padding: 15px 20px;
                position: relative;
                top:-16px;
            }
        }
    }
    .hamburger{
        position: absolute;
        top: 2rem;
        right: 1.8rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 30px;
        height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        .bar{
            height: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:$primary-color;
            border-radius: 10px;
            }
        }
    .hero{
        height: 80vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 1.7;
        h1{
            font-size: $primary-size;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        h2{
            font-size: $secondary-size;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        .bigbar{
            display: inline-block;
            height: 7px;
            width: 45px;
            background-color: $secondary-color;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    }
}
.active{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.bgdark{
    background-position: left bottom;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.inactive{
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const open = ()=> {
        const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
        const header=document.querySelector("header");
        const hero=document.querySelector(".hero");
        nav.classList.toggle(".active");
        header.classList.toggle(".bgdark");
        hero.classList.toggle(".inactive");
    };
};
```

Comment: You don't seem to have included the code which is throwing the error?

Comment: Exactly, I cant seem to find that.

Comment: There error is not being produced by the code in the question. It looks like it's coming from Grammarly?

Comment: I added the whole error message

Comment: @Lurking That exception doesn't seem to come from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the issue here is that the `open()` function is a reserved method on the `window` object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
So when you add `open()` on the `onclick` argument it will fire the `window.open()` method, which whenever executed without any arguments just opens a black page (hence no DOM to be inspected)

So one of the easy fixes is just to rename the function to anything that is not already a standard method of the `window` object. Or just add an anonymous function as a callback to the click event in the js file

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    const header=document.querySelector("header");
    const hero=document.querySelector(".hero");
    nav.classList.toggle("active");
    header.classList.toggle("bgdark");
    hero.classList.toggle("inactive");
});
```

and here's some simple fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5hdk1op4/

Comment: I don’t see how the name open would be an issue. It’s scoped to the anonymous function.